# How to convert hex encoded bytes to String in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, byte

I read some value from Windows Registry (SAM) with Python3. As far as I can tell it looks like hex encoded bytes:

```
    >>> b = b'A\x00d\x00m\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00'
    >>> print(b)
    A d m i n i s t r a t o r
```

Now how would I convert that to a String (should be "Administrator")? Using "print" just gives me "A d m i n i s t r a t o r". How to do the conversion correctly without using dirty tricks?

Answer (score 1):

```py
b = b'A\x00d\x00m\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00'
b = b.replace(b'\x00', b'')
print(b)
# b'Administrator'
```

Comment: Sure it works, but is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Every string in ASCII ends at a NULL ('\x00'). You need to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

I propably should have used utf-16 decoding:

```
    >>> b = b'A\x00d\x00m\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00'
    >>> print(b.decode('utf-16'))
    Administrator
```

SORRY!